# CFSpreadsheet formatting fails when using documented approach

Tags: coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

If I try to format a cell with

```
columnFormat = {
    integer = { alignment = "center", dataformat = '#,##0'},

    ...
```

In Adobe's documentation is says:

[image]

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6747.html

I get a

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting option needs to escape the `#`

To make this work, I needed

```
columnFormat = {
    integer = { alignment = "center", dataformat = '##,####0'},
```